# Normalized Graph Cuts Image Segmentation

Tags: image, matlab

I'm implementing the normalized graph-cuts algorithm in MATLAB. Can someone please explain how to proceed after bi-partitioning the second smallest eigen vector. Now I have 2 segments, what is the meaning of "recursively bi-partitioning the segmented parts?"

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a fit question for SO, as it is nota prgoraming problem, but a concept of maths problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively bi-partitioning means that you need to write a recursive function. this function should bi-partition your segment in each iteration. 
you have image I , you make that image to two partition I1 and I2 , then you need to bi-partition each one ,you can call

> I11,I12

and

> I21, I22

and then again bi-partition each segment , you can call that

> I111,I112

and

> I121,I122

, and

> I21,I22

, and

> I221 ,I222

and continue in this way... 
I assume you use Matlab function to solve generalized eigenvalue problem with 'sm' option:

```
[eigvectors,eigvalues]=eigs(L,D,6,'sm')
```

> L is laplacian matrix = D-W
>
> D is diagonal matrix
>
> W is your weight matrix
>    number 6 means that you are looking for 6 eigen vectors , and 'sm' means you are looking for smallest magnitude.

My thesis for my Master degree in AI was about Improving segmentation using Normalized cut ; feel free to ask any questions.